# Impacto del cache instrucción y de datos

Tags: cache

Estoy trabajando con un microprocesador que utiliza la estructura VLIW, algo particular de este procesador (Trimedia-TM1300)es sus memorias cache.

Normalmente la cache de datos es más grande que la de instrucciones. ¿Qué impacto tiene que el cache de instrucciones sera más grande que el de datos?

Si alguien tiene una idea sobre el tema no dude en decirme, muchas gracias